# plugin-info.html not being generated for Maven site

Tags: maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I have a custom Maven plugin for which I want to generate a site. The sole purpose of this site is to automatically document the plugin's available goals. However, when I execute `mvn clean site`, the `plugin-info.html` file is never generated.

Given that the packaging for this module is `maven-plugin`, I assumed that this would automatically be created by the site plugin. I looked at the site plugin's [goals](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/site-mojo.html) to see if this had to explicitly be "turn on", but did find anything. Is there something I am missing that will force the plugin-info.html to be created?

I am using:

- Maven 3.0.3
- maven-site-plugin 3.0

Answer (score 4):

After some debugging I made a jira issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPLUGIN-191. The description contains the workaround I found to fix this problem.